# How to get model id from the global scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent

- Users are related to each other with many to many relationships.
- I have a scope to check if a user is a friend of the user who sends the request.
- There is a request that fetches all users.

I need to write a condition in my query to check if the pivot table contains an entry with the `friend_id` column equals to the id of the querying user. Here is the apply method of my scope:

```
class IsFriendScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if (!auth()->check()) return;
        $id = $model->id;
        $authId = auth()->id();
        $builder->selectSub(function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query) use ($authId, $id) {
            $query->selectRaw("EXISTS(SELECT * FROM friendships WHERE user_id = $authId AND friend_id = $id)");
        }, 'is_friend');
    }
}
```

The query does not work, as the `$model` variable is always null. So what is the way of achieving this goal?

Comment: you need to pass $model when calling apply method, why is $model always null?

Comment: @Psycho , the method is called by the framework. I do not pass the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function apply(Builder $builder)
{
    $model = $builder->getModel();

}
```

Comment: It is null always. I tried all the possible methods. It seems, it should be done on the SQL side.